# android: referring to ressources in custom xml

Tags: android, resources, localization

i have a multilingual android app, where i have put the different translations in the strings.xml in the respective directory.

now i also have a custom xml file, where i would like to reference texts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rooms>
    <room title="@+string/localizedtext" />
</rooms>
```

now when i read the title attribute in my code, i obviously get the unresolved string "@+string/localizedtext" like it is. 
is it possible to somehow resolve this link to the localized text automatically?

thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could share more about what you're trying to accomplish? As I mentioned below, the @+ construct is for creating a new reference and in the case of @string this doesn't make sense. I don't believe you intend to create a new string here but create a new reference to a different string resource. It would help to know the use case for your code example.

Comment: i am facing EXACTLY this problem.... got any answer?

Answer (score 6):

Almost a year later:

```
    public static String getStringResource(Context context, String thingie) {
        try {
            String[] split = thingie.split("/");
            String pack = split[0].replace("@", "");
            String name = split[1];
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, pack, context.getPackageName());
            return context.getResources().getString(id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return thingie;
        }
    }
```

That'll do it.

Comment: This should be the answer to this particular question.  Cut and paste this lovely function, and bob is your uncle. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This might seem like a broad answer but I believe it'll clarify a lot of things for people who spent hours looking for it (I'm one of them).

The short answer is yes, you can use references in custom XML, not just for strings, but that's the example I use, for ease of understanding.

Considering the context:

- res/values/strings.xml
  *(Default strings, usually en-US for convenience but that's up to the developer)*

```xml
    <resources>
        <string name="sample_string">This is a sample string.</string>
    </resources>
```

- res/values-fr/strings.xml
  *(Localized french strings)*

```xml
    <resources>
        <string name="sample_string">Ceci est un exemple de chaîne</string>
    </resources>
```

- res/xml/test.xml
  *(Custom XML file)*

```xml
    <!-- @string/sample_string identifies both
         the default and french localized strings,
         the system settings determine which is used at runtime.
    -->
    <test>
        <sample name="sampleName" text="@string/sample_string"/>
    </test>
```

- src/com/example/app/TestXmlParser.java

```java
    //Omitted imports for clarity.

    public class testXmlParser {
        public static final String ns = null;

        public int parse(XmlResourceParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
                                                          IOException{
            while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                    if(parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sample")){

                        // This is what matters, we're getting a
                        // resource identifier and returning it.
                        return parser.getAttributeResourceValue(ns, "text", -1);    
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

---

Use `String getText(int id)` to obtain the string corresponding to `id` (localized, if available).

Using the example above it would amount to replace :

```
//Return the resource id
return parser.getAttributeResourceValue(ns, "text", -1);
```

with :

```
//Return the localized string corresponding to the id.
int id = parser.getAttributeResourceValue(ns, "text", -1);
return getString(id);
```

Comment: What about the case where the developer is not using a localized string?  Other attributes handle both scenarios automatically, but this method will fail there.

Comment: If only the default is available that's what getString will return. (Sorry for the late answer)

Answer (score 4):

The way you tried is not possible.

You might get similar functionality with [`<string-array>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) resource:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="room">
        <item>@string/localizedText</item>
        <item>@string/otherLocalizedText</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

then you would use it like this :

```
String[] room = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.room);
String localizedText = room[0];
String otherLocalizedText = room[1];
```

Comment: This leaves the developer to handle localization in code when Android already has ways to localize strings.

Comment: `@string/localizedText` gets localized by OS.

Comment: Parent already told you this is not what he is looking for. And thank you for -1. I'll remove my -1 when you remove yours.

Comment: I understand your solution to suggest two strings, localizedText and otherLocalizedText, to contain the same content in two different localizations. Is this not the case?

Comment: No, when you use `@string/whatever` the OS will look for the `<string name="whatever">some localized text</string>` in the correct `/res/values-xx/filename.xml` file, where `xx` is localization of your device.

Comment: Then maybe we can agree that it's unclear that it's unclear what the OP wants to accomplish? Oh, and SO locked-in my vote, and probably yours too.

Comment: I know what he wants to accomplish - it's just not possible the way he wants it. I suggested an alternative way (not that I'd use it in my code). It's up to him to decide if this works for him.

Comment: Just minimally edit your answer to get it unlocked. I did mine, should be unlocked now.

Answer (score 1):

Localization in Android is done with resource identifiers. Check out this Android tutorial.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

See discussion below.

Comment: yes i know this is already what i do, but it does not relate to my question.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to create a new reference to an empty string resource. I guess I'm unclear as to what you mean for this to accomplish. It seemed to me that you need to simply access the value of a string resource. Is this incorrect?

Comment: well, i have all my texts in the strings.xml for all languages. and localization works if use them directly. my question is how can i refer to them in other xml files (my own custom xml file)

Comment: Edit your post pls to unlock it (just add a whitespace somewhere). I cant remove the downvote.

Comment: What kind of custom XML is this? A layout perhaps? Just drop the plus sign and call the string reference by name. Also, do all your localized string references have unique names? Each translation of a particular bit of content should have the same reference name. For example, to have a greeting in multiple languages you could have a string named "hello" in both values-en and values-es and their values are "Hello" and Hola" respectively.

Comment: the custom xml looks like the example i have posted. just with more rooms. ;) and even if i remove the plus sign it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Great answer kyis, shame I still don't have enough brownie points to rate it. To answer Nick's question, just change the last bit of code to:

```
int id = parser.getAttributeResourceValue(ns, "text", 0);
return (id != 0) ? getString(id) : parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "text");
```

Note that I used 0 for the default value of the resource as this is guaranteed never to be a real resource value. -1 would have done also.